# StableMarriage vs. FindIndependendEdgeSet: How to use the procedure FindIndependendEdgeSet as a Gale-Shapley algorithm?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

From Help, the procedure `StableMarriage` was an element of the `Combinatorica`, but it is available in the built-in `FindIndependentEdgeSet` since Mathematica 10.

But it is not clear from the documentation how to use  `FindIndependentEdgeSet` as a Gale-Shapley algorithm straightforwardly. So, the procedure `FindIndependentEdgeSet` can find an independent edge set and, for weighted graphs, maximal total-valued independent edge set. But this is no the same as a stable matching. How to solve it?

Explicitly: The input of the `StableMarriage` is a pair of permutations describing male and female preferences. But that is not acceptable input for `FindIndependentEdgeSet` procedure

Comment: I think that the fact that you got multiple upvotes but no answers indicates that how to do this is not at all obvious (if possible at all!). I would contact Wolfram Support and ask about it. They should be able to contact whoever wrote that documentation page and ask for clarifications.

Comment: tried ``SparseArray`StableMarriage[mpref, fpref]`` (where `mpref` and `fpref` are the matrices of male and female preferences)?

Answer (score 8):

The function FindStableMatching is now in the Wolfram Function Repository:

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FindStableMatching/